# How do you give material-ui drawer component a switchable theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes, navigation-drawer

I am making a react project but I have a problem getting my material-ui drawer to match with my dark/light switchable theme. I currently have given the drawer styling using makeStyles, but I can't for the life of me get it sync with ThemeProvider.

I have tried doing it all in ThemeProvider but the drawer required other methods. Then I tried doing it all with makeStyles and not using ThemeProvider at all but that didn't work either. I also tried putting a conditional ternary statement in makeStyles for this, but that didn't work.

Any help or advice that leads me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function App() {

  const dark_theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {  
      primary: {
        main: '#e78f23',
      secondary: {
        main: '#463d3d',
      }
    },
    background: {
      default: "#222222",
    },
    text: {
      primary: "#ffffff"
  },
}
  })

  const light_theme = createMuiTheme({
    palete: {
      primary: {
        main: '#4892BC',
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#EEF3FF',
      },
      background: {
        default: "#e4f0e2"
      },
      text: {
        primary: "#000000"
    },
    }
  });
  
  


  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    drawer: {
      background : '#e78f23',
    },
    switchTrack: {
      backgroundColor: "#000"
    },
    switchBase: {
      color: "#000",
      "&.Mui-checked": {
        color: "white"
      },
      "&.Mui-checked + .MuiSwitch-track": {
        backgroundColor: "white"
      },
    },
  }));
    
  const classes = useStyles()

  const [light, setLight] = useState(true);
```

```js
return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={light ? light_theme : dark_theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Router>
      <main>
        <Drawer id="Drawer" PaperProps={{className:classes.drawer}}  open={drawerOpen} onClose={CloseDrawer}>
          
          <List id="ListID">
          
            <Button>
              <ListItem button onClick={() => setLight(prev => !prev)} color="primary" class="themeButton">
                <FormControl>
                  <FormLabel>Dark/Light</FormLabel>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <FormControlLabel
                          id="formControlLabel"
                          control = {
                            <Switch2
                              color="default"
                              classes={{
                                track: classes.switchTrack,
                                switchBase: classes.switchBase,
                              }}
                              size="medium"
                              position="center"
                              checked={checked}
                              onChange={toggleChecked}
                              labelPlacement="end"
                            />
                          }
                        />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </FormControl>
              </ListItem>
            </Button>
```